# Efficient HTTP shutdown with keepalives?

Tags: node.js, http

This Node.js server will shutdown cleanly on a Ctrl+C when all connections are closed.

```
var http = require('http');
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.end('Hello');
});

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  console.log('Closing...');
  app.close(function () {
    console.log('Closed.');
    process.exit();
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The problem with this is that it includes keepalive connections. If you open a tab to this app in Chrome and then try to Ctrl+C it, it won't shutdown for about 2 minutes when Chrome finally releases the connection.

Is there a clean way of detecting when there are no more HTTP requests, even if some connections are still open?

Comment: Can you close the listening socket and then fire up a new server immediately?  Then you can let this one close whenever it's done, and it doesn't matter how long it takes.

Comment: If I start a new server in the same process, yes, it can start listening and accept new connections there. I'd like to be able to actually wait for the process to stop before start a new one, but maybe that's me clinging to old ways. If nothing else, it's useful during development.

Comment: Yeah, let it go.  :)  Or perhaps drop the keepalive timeout so 5 seconds.  This is a common strategy anyway, at least for apache.  Node is obviously different but it's not necessarily crazy.  Also - you *should* be able to start a new process and bind the socket so long as this one has closed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default there's no socket timeout, that means that connections will be open forever until the client closes them. If you want to set a timeout use this function: [socket.setTimeout](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback).

If you try to close the server you simply can't because there are active connections, so if you try to gracefully shutdown the shutdown function will hang up. The only way is to set a timeout and when it expires kill the app.

If you have workers it's not as simple as killing the app with `process.exit()`, so I made a module that does extacly what you're asking: [grace](https://github.com/Gagle/Node-Grace).

Comment: You're right that in general, if a connection's open then it's open, and you either have to time it out or just wait indefinitely. But specifically with HTTP, if the connection is not going to serve any further HTTP requests then it is no longer 'active', and can be closed on that basis.

Comment: I went with defining a small request-counting module that exposed an Express middleware, and that is doing the job for me. However marking your answer as correct because I like the look of `grace` and I may well start using it, especially when I start using child workers.

Answer (score 2):

You can hack some request tracking with the `finish` event on response:

```
var reqCount = 0;

var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  reqCount++;
  res.on('finish', function() { reqCount--; });
  res.end('Hello');
});
```

Allowing you to check whether reqCount is zero when you come to close the server.

The correct thing to do, though, is probably to not care about the old server and just start a new one. Usually the restart is to get new code, so you can start a fresh process without waiting for the old one to end, optionally using the `child_process` module to have a toplevel script managing the whole thing. Or even use the `cluster` module, allowing you to start the new process before you've even shut down the old one (since `cluster` manages balancing traffic between its child instances).

One thing I haven't actually tested very far, is whether it's guaranteed safe to start a new server as soon as `server.close()` returns. If not, then the new server could potentially fail to bind. There's an example in the [`server.listen()`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback) docs about how to handle such an `EADDRINUSE` error.

Comment: Oops, [I stand corrected](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/).

Comment: You still have a point - if you had any other stuff, like a pending timer callback, then you would need to shut all that down in addition to the HTTP server. Otherwise the process wouldn't naturally exit.